# No password required in Xubuntu after waking up

Tags: xubuntu, password

I am experiencing a very frustrating issue while running Xubuntu 13.04.

It seems like Xubuntu does not need to require the password, when pulling the lid over.

I already tried to search for a fix on the world wide web: unfortunately, I did not find any working solution about it.

Then, I decided to search on Ask Ubuntu for a conceivable settlement: I read about a similar issue right in this thread -> [Xubuntu: No password request after suspension](https://askubuntu.com/questions/259190/xubuntu-no-password-request-after-suspension/359734#359734)

I tried to follow both of the solutions therein listed, but (unfortunately) I had no luck in solving the problem.

Can You kindly consider to help me finding a better elucidation?

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: And what release of Xubuntu are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Have you tried `xscreensaver`?**

- Install it by following commands if not already installed:

  ```
  sudo apt-get -f install xscreensaver
  ```
- Open it from **Application Menu -> Settings -> Screensaver** or type `xscreensaver` in your terminal
- Under <kbd>Display Mode</kbd> tab `tick` the **Lock Screen After** check-box after giving appropriate value.
- That's it..

**Alternate way to get the lock screen**

`xautolock` and `xlock` would definitely help you if above doesn't work for you.

- Install two packages by executing following commands:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install xautolock xlockmore
  ```
- Once installed press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to and type `xautolock -time 1` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to run `xlock` daemon.
- Wait and see.. :) Your screen will be locked in 1 minute. You can give any time you want. you're screen will be locked after every idle of 1 minute.
- To stop the `xlock` daemon  <sub>i,e if you don't want to lock your screen any more</sub> type followng command in terminal:

  ```
  xautolock -exit
  ```

Reply if it helps you too.. :) Please give me some time so that I could write the script to run the `xlock` daemon on every system start.

Comment: Thank you so much Saurav Kumar: it seems like Xscreensaver did solve the issue. Thank you so, so much.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Debian Jessie with xfce and had a similar issue. Password after suspend was required but not after wake up from hibernation.

I ticked the box `Lock screen when going for suspend` in the `Xfce Power Manager - Extended` GUI to no avail. Then I followed the advice in the above mentioned post [Xubuntu: No password request after suspension](https://askubuntu.com/questions/259190/xubuntu-no-password-request-after-suspension/359734#359734) for *terminal commands*. The only command needed was

```
xfconf-query -c xfce4-power-manager -p /xfce4-power-manager/lock-screen-suspend-hibernate -s true
```

Now I'm asked for my password after waking up from hibernation.