# Xubuntu: Turn off password after suspend

Tags: xubuntu, password, suspend

On a new install of 14.10 beta, I'm getting prompted for my password when the laptop is coming back from suspend (ie closing the laptop lid). Weirdly, everyone else seems to have the opposite problem. I checked this question:

[Xubuntu: No password request after suspension](https://askubuntu.com/questions/259190/xubuntu-no-password-request-after-suspension/359734#359734)

I used the GUI method and did the opposite of what it says, but I'm still getting prompted for a password. Are there any other places I can look for a setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Light Locker settings there is a toggle switch, "Lock on Suspend"

Light Locker Settings (/usr/share/light-locker-settings/light-locker-settings/light-locker-settings.py) are found in `xfce4-settings-manager`

Comment: I had looked in there, and "Lock on Suspend" was turned off. However, it was the hint I needed, and I tried disabling the Light Locker entirely and that has fixed the problem! Thank you!